# Ruby concatenating best practice

Tags: ruby

I need to solve a simple issue in Ruby, but want to do it in a smart way. I have a function:

```
def fullname
  first + " " + mi + last
end
```

That will crash if one or more of the variables is `nil`, let's say mi for this example since it's in the center.

Error:

> can't convert nil into String

If I change the function to:

```
def fullname
  first + " " + mi.to_s + last
end
```

or

```
def fullname
  first + " " + (mi || "") + last
end
```

It will fix it. Now I want to add an additional space after the mi (middle initial) if it is present and I'm stumped for some silly reason. What would be the cleanest way to do something like this, as I will be having to do it a lot and sometimes adding say a comma.

Example of that need:

```
def fullname
  first + " " + (mi || "") + last + suffix 
  # want a ", " afer the last name if there is a suffix
end
```

Comment: You shouldn't rely on fullnames having a defined schema: http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-personal-names

Comment: @DamienMATHIEU: Baby steps, my friend. The OP is a self-described newbie; don't overwhelm him ;)

Comment: Thank-you and 110% understand that this isn't internationalized at all yet. Need to get some of these basics down before I can cross that bridge I think. Thank-you for the article, definitely something I need to read and understand!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
def fullname
  [[first, *mi, last].join(" "), *suffix].join(", ")
end
```

Comment: That works great for the spaces, thank-you! Is there a tweak that would allow for it to be a space sometimes or other times a comma? I will update my question to reflect that better.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, deleted my comment. I was building on your great examples and it probably looked like I was asking if your code was bad, when I was asking if mine was bad. Thank you for the help!!!!!

Comment: Despite it being a solution for this particular case. You shouldn't really use this kind of cryptic code. You can't tell at first sight that this produces a string and therefore might be confusing for those that will read the code after you. Please take a look at *string interpolation* instead.

Comment: @Jeffrey Would you post an answer using string interpolation?

Comment: @MechDog I wondered what it meant when the comment was half way written. Now, I understand. Now I see that you moved your accepted answer.

Comment: Lol, thought I could accept more then one. Sorry, need to learn more about the interface is all. There's just no point in being stupid if you can't show it;-)

Comment: @sawa, it would be redundant since [Dan Tao](http://stackoverflow.com/users/105570/dan-tao) already did that.

Comment: @Jeffrey Dan Tao's answer with interpolation has problem of inserting an extra space when `mi` is absent.

Comment: @sawa, what do you mean by *absent*?

Comment: @Jeffrey Being `nil`.

Comment: @Jeffrey `nil` is not taking up the space, the spaces at both sides of it in `"#{first} #{mi} #{last}"` are. (Note to others: This is a reply to a deleted comment by Jeffrey).

Comment: I am running into it running different if the variable is "" instead of nil. For this function it would be better if those both were treated as nil. I added suffix == " ? suffix=nil : "" ahead of it, but I know this is less then ideal as it is changing the value of the object.

Comment: @MechDog If you want to deal with empty strings, you may need to add `.reject(&:empty?)` after the arrays.

Comment: @sawa, that definitely makes it even smoother result! I added .reject(&:empty?) to both and removed the other code. Thanks yet again!!!

Answer (score 9):

**First**: I would actually say that the most "Ruby" way of handling this—avoiding the `nil` issue, that is—would be to use *string interpolation*:

```
"#{first} #{mi} #{last}"
```

This works just fine in case any of the above variables is `nil`, because it will simply result in blank space in the string.

**As for the conditional space issue**: There are plenty of ways to skin that cat. I really like [sawa's idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17814805/105570). Here's another, which I've seen variants of, though it's not particularly efficient (but 9 times out of 10 that doesn't matter):

```
[first, mi, last].compact.join(" ")
```

**Lastly**: for the "plus comma + suffix if present" requirement, that's complicated enough that I'd recommend writing a little method to separate that logic out:

```
def suffix_if_necessary(name)
  suffix ? "#{name}, #{suffix}" : name
end

def fullname
  suffix_if_necessary([first, *mi, last].join(" "))
end
```

But again, there are multiple ways to get the job done here. Whatever works for you.

Comment: That does look cleaner for sure. Am I thinking correctly that if there is no mi variable there would be 2 spaces between the first and last name instead of just one?

Comment: @MechDog: Yep, that's correct. I just updated the answer to address your requirement for conditional spacing. As I concede, it isn't particularly efficient; but since these are just three little strings the performance and memory impact should be negligible.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Both solutions seem to work and I'm sure each one will have its place. Thanks for helping to get this newbie out of a jam point! Learned a bunch from you and @sawa and I thank-you both for your time and effort!!!

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you to use *string interpolation* to make it clear that you are returning a string from that method (and will also ignore `nil` values):

```
def fullname
    s = "#{first} #{mi} #{last}".lstrip.rstrip.squeeze(' ')
    s += ", #{suffix}" if suffix
end
```

Comment: How does that handle the optional `suffix`?

Comment: And you say that this is not cryptic?

Comment: @sawa, The most cryptic thing about this is the `String#+=` method. Go figure. Also this is not iterating over any array (especially multidimensional) and therefore has, *theoretically* little complexity over, your solution for example.

Comment: I thought you posted this to show you can have an answer with interpolation that is not "cryptic" as mine.